# What is the simplest EEG detecting circuit possible?

Tags: arduino, eeg

Suppose I took an Arduino and hooked it up to two electrodes: one to the front part of my head going into A0 and another connecting my earlobe to ground, why wouldn't this system be capable of measuring mV scale EEG signals?

Comment: EEG is tens of microvolts.

Comment: The LSB of the ADC on Arduino is many millivolts.

Comment: Power grid noise (50Hz/60Hz received by the leads) greatly exceeds the amplitude of the signal to be measured, so a good notch filter is essential. This is bad enough for pro medical devices where there is double insulation to prevent a fault in the electronics from harming or killing the patient, it is even worse in a non-isolated hobbyist system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a really good article that discusses EEG from the ground up

The neurophysiological bases of EEG and EEG measurement: A review for the rest of us